# Sign in with Google button causes annoying logs that freeze my website

Tags: javascript, google-signin, freeze

I recently added the Sign in with Google button to my website using the Google Identity Platform and followed their docs. Everything works fine but I'm seeing these requests in the console and everytime one happens my entire website freezes, and this is a huge problem since it's a game.

The logs are being blocked by an AdBlocker but they still manage to freeze the entire game.

The logs are like the following:

[image: POST https://play.google.com/log?format=json&hasfast=true&authuser=0 net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT]

Is there any way to stop these?

Comment: You should add a snippet of your code, from the error message we cannot see what goes wrong. It's probably a unresolved promise, but without code we can't be certain.

Comment: Don't use google's provided code? Just use an open-source OIDC client instead.

Comment: @S.Visser the code that makes the error isn't mine, it's from Google: `https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client`

Comment: @AndrewGillis but OpenID doesn't use Google to sign in, does it? I need it to be Google because I have already made all of the backend code